# Antd Select not setting initial value

Tags: reactjs, forms, antd

I have an issue in setting the initial value in antd Select

```
const options=[{name:'john',id:1},{name:'jack',id:2},{name:'jill',id:3}]
   <Form initialValues={{user:3}}>
    <Form.Item name="user" label="Select user">
        <Select value="3">
        {options.map((user,index)=><Option key={index} value={user.id}>{user.name}</Option>)}
        </Select>
    </Form.Item>
   </Form>
```

It's not selecting the initial value. Any idea in this. is this a correct way of implementing it, please help

Comment: Can you please add working demo so we can take better look? Thanks!

Comment: I just figured out API response Id having an issue thanks issue fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below is a simple demo of Select Component in Antd Form
I am wondering whether the options come from the store or other components? So the form does not get the initial values once the form is mounted. If it comes from other source, you need to subscribe the initial values if it changes to reset the antd form like

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { Form, Input, Button, Checkbox, Select } from 'antd';
const layout = {
  labelCol: {
    span: 8,
  },
  wrapperCol: {
    span: 16,
  },
};
const tailLayout = {
  wrapperCol: {
    offset: 8,
    span: 16,
  },
};
// useEffect(() => {
  //   form.resetFields()
  //   form.setFieldsValue({
  //     productName: productName
  //   })
  // }, [initialValues]);
const userNameOptions = [{name:'john',id:1},{name:'jack',id:2},{name:'jill',id:3}]
const Demo = () => {
  const onFinish = (values) => {
    console.log('Success:', values);
  };

  const onFinishFailed = (errorInfo) => {
    console.log('Failed:', errorInfo);
  };

  return (
    <Form
      {...layout}
      name="basic"
      initialValues={{
        remember: true,
        username: 3
      }}
      onFinish={onFinish}
      onFinishFailed={onFinishFailed}
    >
      <Form.Item
        label="Username"
        name="username"
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: 'Please input your username!',
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Select value='3'>
          {userNameOptions.map((item, index) => (
            <Select.Option key={index} value={item.id}>
              {item.name}
            </Select.Option>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item
        label="Password"
        name="password"
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: 'Please input your password!',
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Input.Password />
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item {...tailLayout} name="remember" valuePropName="checked">
        <Checkbox>Remember me</Checkbox>
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item {...tailLayout}>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this working in ant design 4.
If you only need to set the value once use defaultValue and pass a string prop

```
defaultValue={!!props.DefaultString && claimId}
```

You can however set the values for both the current value and the options by using form.setFieldsValue in useEffect.

e.g.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        form.setFieldsValue({
            SelectValue: !!props.selectItemValue && props.props.claimId,
            SelectableOptions: (!!props.selectableOptions? props.selectableOptions : undefined)
        );
    }
}, [props,form]);


<Form.Item name="SelectValue" >
    <Select >
        {!!props.selectableOptions && props.selectableOptions.map((opt) => <Option key={opt.id} value={opt.id}>{opt.name}</Option>)} 
    </Select>
 </Form.Item>
```

NB: Use the props directly rather than the fieldValue for the options

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Form, Select } from 'antd';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const { Option } = Select;

function MyForm() {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();

  const initialValues = {
    mySelect: 'option2',
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    form.setFieldsValue(initialValues);
  }, [form, initialValues]);

  return (
    <Form form={form} initialValues={initialValues}>
      <Form.Item name="mySelect" label="My Select">
        <Select>
          <Option value="option1">Option 1</Option>
          <Option value="option2">Option 2</Option>
          <Option value="option3">Option 3</Option>
        </Select>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
}
```